# AOT Angular 2 ignore library

Tags: angular, konvajs

Is it possible to ignore certain files or dependencies when doing an AOT angular 2+ build?

We have an essential library in our project that compiles successfully but the project will not run. Even though there were no compilation errors, the app comes up blank when served and gives the error `Error: Cannot find module “.”`

The library in question is Konva and I'm wondering if I can exclude Konva from AOT when I use `ngc` to build a production angular 2+ application?

Comment: If you are using angular 6 + cli you could use a different configuration definition to exclude that library from the build.

Comment: That would then mean that library would not be available in the build correct? So the application would fail when it required those files? I'm new to aot so I may be missing something